# Creating a generic VMware control library

Tags: c#, vmware

In our organization, we're running several VM solutions from VMware:

- VMware ESX
- VMware ESXi (now called Hypervisor/vSphere)
- VMware Workstation

I'd like to be able to control all of these in a transparent way (send power commands, revert to a given snapshot to begin with) as part of an automated process of our product.

My problem is that there are far too many APIs and i've failed to find any good samples on how to achieve this.

Anyone has any experience with creating this sort of library? which VMware APIs need to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the VIX API here: [VIX API Reference Common Task](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix110_reference/index2.html). It's COM based, so you'll have to import the COM object as a reference.

See also this article here: [Automating VMWare Tasks in C# with the VIX API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/VMWareTasks.aspx)

Comment: I wonder if VIX can be used to control all the types of different VMware technologies (ESX/ESXi/etc)